# CSS: hover state remains active after going back (Firefox)

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, hover, back

I try to apply two different styles to a link: when hovered over, and when not. While this works perfectly in Chrome and Opera, when I follow the link in Firefox or Midori and then go back by clicking the 'Back'-button in the navigationbar, the link still appears like being hovered over. As soon as I move the cursor back over any part of the website it changes back to normal.

Is this a webkit related behaviour and is there any way to avoid it?

EDIT:

I found an official Mozilla demo of a dropdown menu (which is what I'm actually trying to do) that has the exact same problem: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3700/css_dropdown_menu.html

When clicking a menu option and then going back, the before opened sub-menu is still open until the mouse is hovered back over the site.

Comment: The Mozilla demo doesn't have functioning links, so it is hard to reproduce the scenario you are talking about. I'd suggest throwing together something quickly in JSFiddle or the like so that the good folks here can better help out.

Comment: Have you tried to set the pseudo selector with your desired colors? Smt like this: http://jsbin.com/viwuhemiqi  please let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the LOVEHATE rule. LOVEHATE being a mnemonic technique to help remember Link, Visited, Hover, and Active. Your styles should always stipulate every one of these link states and always in this specific order. For example:

```
a:link {color: #333;}
a:visited {color: #333;}
a:hover {color: #999;}
a:active {color: #333;}
```